# WPF different SelectedItem in different contexts

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a tree-shaped graph of data that I need to display to the user and let the user pick from. For simplicity's sake, let's say I have a list of streets, each containing a list of houses, each containing a list of people there living. Something like this:

```
interface IStreet {
    string Name {get;}
    IReadOnlyCollection<IHouse> Houses {get;}
}

interface IHouse {
    int StreetNumber {get;}
    IReadOnlyCollection<IPerson> People {get;}
}

interface IPerson {
    string Name {get;}
}
```

I have a form in WPF where the user is supposed to select 2 different persons, but both of them have to live in the same street. Something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|  Street:                                       |
|  +------------------------------------------+  |
|  | Pick street                            ▾ |  |
|  +------------------------------------------+  |
|                                                |
|  + - Person 1 (Group box) - - - - - - - - - +  |
|  |  House:                                  |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |  | Pick house                       ▾ |  |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |                                          |  |
|  |  Person:                                 |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |  | Pick peron                       ▾ |  |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+  |
|                                                |
|  + - Person 2 (Group box) - - - - - - - - - +  |
|  |  House:                                  |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |  | Pick house                       ▾ |  |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |                                          |  |
|  |  Person:                                 |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |  | Pick peron                       ▾ |  |  |
|  |  +------------------------------------+  |  |
|  + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+  |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

I started by having the "Pick street" ComboBox have it's `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` set to true, and binding the two group-boxes' `DataContext` to `{Binding Path=Streets/}`. My hope was that by setting the `DataContext` of the group-boxes it would create separate contexts, so that when I bound the House-ComboBox to `{Binding Path=Houses}` and set it to synchronize with the current item they would maintain each their own "Current Item", however, this did not happen. So now, when I pick a house for any one of the persons, the other changes as well. My question is, is there any elegant way I can make this setup work with binding, or do I have to go back to the manual way of populating the comboboxes `OnChange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a default CollectionViewSource on the persons in the Street (I always think of these as cursors).

To have two cursors, you need **two** [CollectionViewSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).

You can make these in code or Xaml and bind the groupboxes to the two CollectionViewSources

Comment: That was a lot better than what I came up with. I used a IValueConverter to make a copy of the collection for each of the `GroupViews`.

Comment: A copy (although not by using a valueconverter) might still be needed when you want to manipulate the lists and/or their items. Still, that will cause a serious headache when trying to envision what possible scenario's could occur from a concurrency point of view.

Comment: The collections are ReadOnly for a reason. No mutations are supposed to happen, so concurrency shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes. They only have getters :) . The data is read from disk (db or flat files) and the user only has to pick 2.